# Can I use SwipeRefreshLayout as a footer inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, footer, progressdialog, swiperefreshlayout

I want to add a progress bar like `SwipeRefreshLayout` in android as a footer inside my `RecyclerView` for loading more contents. Does SwipeRefreshLayout provide this functionality or not? If not, then how can I add a progress bar as a footer in the RecyclerView?